# Android uploading PDF file through retrofit is giving SSL Exception

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Here is my code for uploading files to Retrofit:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 3) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,uri);
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            strPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            senddata1(strPath )
        }
    }
}

private void senddata1(String path) {
    if(common.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
        Log.d("TestTag","filename : "+path+" file : "+strfile);
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        submit_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        File file = new File(path);
    // Parsing any Media type file
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
    RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
  
    APIService getResponse = apiclient.imgUpload().create(APIService.class);
    Call<ImageUpload> call = getResponse.uploadFile(fileToUpload,filename);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageUpload>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ImageUpload> call, Response<ImageUpload> response) {
            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            submit_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String message=response.body().getMessage();
                String type=response.body().getType();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ImageUpload> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            submit_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("TestTag","throwable : "+t);
            common.showtoast("Failed to upload image.",getApplicationContext());
        }
    }}
   }
}
```

I am implementing camera, gallery and filemanager intent in my app and uploading the selected files to server using retrofit. When I try to upload PDF files to server I am getting SSL Exception or sometimes I am getting timeout exception.

A few days before the above code is worked perfectly when I upload pdf files. but now it's not working.

Comment: does your server have SSL certificate? also please share the error log

Comment: It's because of _SSL Certificate_

Comment: Already our server has SSL certificate

Comment: I am struggling with this past two days i tried all the examples of uploading files dont know why its not working

Comment: Have you checked the size of PDF? Also what is the maximum upload size is set to at your server?

Comment: there is no maximum size restriction from my server